# Cosmos Container SQL API Query

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I've a document structure below (simplified):

```
 {
"id": "2345",
"camp{
    "id": 999
    "code": "C1244
    "offers": [
        {
            "status": "active",
            "description": "Commence Loyalty At Year 6"
        },
        {
            "status": "inactive"
            "description": "abcd test
        }
    }
}
```

Where I would like to filter the offers where status is active.  Can someone help me with what the query may look like for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try something like this sql:

```
SELECT  c.camp.id,c.camp.code,d AS offer FROM c join d in c.camp.offers where d.status = 'active'
```

Here is the result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 999,
        "code": "C1244",
        "offer": {
            "status": "active",
            "description": "Commence Loyalty At Year 6"
        }
    }
]
```

Hope this can help you:).